# In C how to test for a NULL value in remaining strtok srting before trying to tokenize

Tags: c

I am not able to work out how to test for a NULL value before continuing with tokenizing `strtok`.

given

```
char* myStr = "a,b,c";
char item_a[1];
char item_b[1];
char item_c[1];
strcpy(item_a, strtok( myStr, ","));
strcpy(item_b, strtok( NULL, ","));
strcpy(item_c, strtok( NULL, ","));
```

produces as expected

```
item_a = a
item_b = b
item_c = c
```

but, the following gives a segmentation fault on `strcpy(item_c, strtok( NULL, ","));`, how do I test that `NULL` in `strtok( NULL,` is not actually `NULL`, if you know what I mean?

```
char* myStr = "a,b";
char item_a[1];
char item_b[1];
char item_c[1];
strcpy(item_a, strtok( myStr, ","));
strcpy(item_b, strtok( NULL, ","));
strcpy(item_c, strtok( NULL, ","));
```

Comment: try `char myStr[] = "a,b,c";
char item_a[2];
char item_b[2];
char item_c[2];`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you always find buffer overflows first!

Comment: so you got it: the problem is not a null value, it's a buffer overflow when copying to undersized arrays. And if you know that your arrays have 1 char, there are simpler ways than strtok!

Comment: in 2nd case `char myStr[] = "a,b";` and `strcpy(item_c, strtok( NULL, ","));` : `strtok` return `NULL`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, this was just an example. I actually don't know the lenght yet and in some cases the function will not be passed the same number of parameters, so I need to test before continuing. Unfortunately the comment by BLUEPIXY does not take this into account, so I need a fuller answer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so there is no way to test if the remaining string is !NULL before continuing?

Comment: just assign `char *t = strtok( NULL, ",");` and only perform copy if `t!=NULL`

Comment: @artvanderlay Separate function calls.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the return value of `strtok` immediately, save it in a pointer and test it first.

From the man page:

> The `strtok()` and `strtok_r()` functions return  a  pointer  to  the 
>   next
>          token, or `NULL` if there are no more tokens.

So when `strtok` returns NULL, you know you're at the end of the string.

```
char* myStr = "a,b,c", *p;
char item_a[2];
char item_b[2];
char item_c[2];
p = strtok( myStr, ",");
if (p) {
    strcpy(item_a, p);
    p = strtok( NULL, ",");
    if (p) {
        strcpy(item_b, p);
        p = strtok( NULL, ",");
        if (p) {
            strcpy(item_c, p);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you have enough space in your destination string for each token.  The reason you got a segfault is because your arrays weren't big enough.  You need enough for the length of the string plus one more for the null byte which terminates the string.

Comment: I see repetition! `int parse(size_t times, char s[static (2*times-1)], char items[times][2]) { for (size_t i=0; i < times; i++) { char *p = strtok(s, ","); if (!p) return 1; strcpy(items[i], p); } return 0; }`

Comment: @Qix It does, just having fun refactoring :)

Comment: @YoYoYonnY ?! If you're afraid of refactoring, perhaps programming isn't the field for you.

Comment: @Qix ??! Not sure what you're suggesting... The one who seems to be afraid to refactor is you :|  
I refactored your code because it is such an obvious thing to refactor, because you didn't do it and because `@artvanderlay` doesn't seem to be skilled enough to do it yet. IMHO refactored code would help OP more than raw code.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY I didn't write the code. :) Merely pointing out that the answer still demonstrates the usage correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *myStr = "a,b,c";//unknown size string.
    size_t len = strlen(myStr);//check size
    char *copyStr = malloc(len + 1);
    strcpy(copyStr, myStr);

    char *items = malloc((len+1)/ 2);
    size_t n = 0;

    char *itemp = strtok(copyStr, ",");
    while(itemp != NULL){
        items[n++] = *itemp;
        itemp = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    //check print
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("%c\n", items[i]);
    }
    free(copyStr);
    free(items);
    return 0;
}
```